# IPsec PSK - VPN connection not working in android Phones

Tags: vpn

The VPN connection setup is not working in android phones but whereas the same setup is working fine in iPhone. Is Group password and IPsec pre-shared key are same.

Please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some combination of Android devices and VPN servers which are known not to work fine. For instance, Sony "Z" series phones, running Android version greater than 4.3 are unable to connect to Openswan based VPN servers. Unfortunately your question doesn't give sufficient details on the context (devices used, android version, VPN server specs)